# React looping component and HTML Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In the below React code, My expectation is to iterate a paragraph 5 times with items in the array.
So, In Type one, I directly used `<p></p>` tags to display and got it...
In Type Two, I iterate a new Component which internally has a `p` tag in it... What becomes the difference within these two approaches.. Since in both types, DOM elements are minimized.. Will it affect in any performance strategies or what does it even make it different... Thanks in advance....

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import QuickComp from "./QuickComp";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      // Type One
      {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].map(item => {
        return <p>{item}</p>;
      })}
      <br />
      //Type Two
      {["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].map(item => {
        return <QuickComp name={item} />;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**QuickComp.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function QuickComp(props) {
  return <p>{props.name}</p>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all Don't use map . Simple use forEach.
forEach() does not mutate the array on which it is called.

Comment: err, mutating the array is literally the goal in this case.

Answer (score -1):

When we go for separate component it is reusable in our react project so we can change in one single component instead of change all occurrence. Coming to your question you can see the difference between direct rendering element and multiple usage of p element in your project.

Consider the situation you should use p element in multiple component in our project but all are look wise same and values are different in this situation you can create separate component for p like you did in 2nd method (QuickComp) so that we can reuse it.